# How to solve Gradle / Java incompatibility error message when adding google-services to my build.gradle?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have a flutter / android project that uses

```
gradle 7.5
minSdkVersion 33
java 19 (I've tried 8, 11, 17, 19 & 20)
```

When I add in the google-services classpath dependency to android/build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```

and try to recompile I get an error saying:

> Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version
> that Flutter is using    │ │ for Gradle

If I remove the google-services dependency it compiles, when I add it back in I get the same error.

How to solve this?  I've also tried different versions of google-services but I can't seem to get my app to compile.

Answer (score 0):

I had referenced a dependency that was using a higher level of gradle (it used an Android native feature).  I downgraded that dependency and refrenced it and the project compiled again.